# Self-loop symbol?

Tags: symbols

I am in a need of symbol(s) which would denote the set of self-loops in a graph, usable in a mathematical context. As of now, I'm choosing between

- overlapping the letters `S` and `L`,
- a circle with an arrow tip

The symbol has to maintain its form when switching to a different font or font size. As of now, I don't know whether any of them is already available in some package. Do you know more?

(Note: Unicode is unfortunately out of question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one, the other, or both.  EDITED to handle different font sizes.  Your mileage may vary with different fonts.  Shown here in math mode, but it will produce the same result in text mode, though clearly the `\CircArrowRight` will blow the line spacing if included in inline text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb,graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\SL{\stackengine{.2ex}{S\,}{\,L}{U}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand\CircArrowRight[1]{\stackengine{-.3ex}{\scalebox{.8}{#1}}{\CAR}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand\CAR{\scaleto{\circlearrowright}{3ex}}
\begin{document}
\[
\CircArrowRight{}\,
\CircArrowRight{\SL}{}
\SL
\]

\Huge
\[
\CircArrowRight{}\,
\CircArrowRight{\SL}{}
\SL
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LeonMeier It currently is displayed in math mode, if that is what you mean.  However, maybe you mean, can it be made with an italic "S" and "L"?  I chose to keep them upright, because they are not math variables, but rather an abbreviation for English text.